# Azure DevOps create release branch from particular commit of master branch

Tags: git

I am using Azure DevOps. I forgot to create a release branch from master when it was release to production. I released the master branch to production. The master branch has now got few more merges which I don't want to be released. I want to do hot fixes to production.

Can anyone help me how to create release branch from master to the commit which i released to prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a branch in git from specific commit by just give the commit SHA:

```
git checkout master
git branch release fsaklf3184091flsafjlsafjdsa2 (yout release commit SHA)
```